# working with cutadapt

Tags: python, sequence-analysis, cutadapt

I'm working with ion torrent data where I apply the program cutadapt. 
I'm analyzing ITS seq data, as well as Matk.
When I'm using cutadapt, I search the information for this genes, and built new files accordingly to his information. For instance, when I search for ITS, I generate a file about this gene, and the same applies to the Matk gene.
However, more recently I randomly picked a fasta sequence from ITS, blast it and received the information about the matk gene. Is this supposed to occur?
Thank you for the help and so sorry for the naive question.

Comment: How do you know that you didn't just mix up your Matk and ITS data? Not sure that I understand how you "generate a file".

Answer (score 0):

*Answer from @m, converted from comment:*

It's definitely not supposed to happen. There appears to be a deep rooted classification bug, where matk is misclassified as ITS. Unpicking this will be hard.